# Access UserProfile from NotifyBot

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to kind of merge the functionality of `EchoBot` and `ProactiveBot`. A bot that parses user commands, which can also be triggered through a URL to send some users a message based on the contents of their `UserProfile`.

I managed to get both parts to work, but I'm having trouble accessing the `UserProfile`s from the `NotifyController`, or solving the problem another way. I tried a few things, read many of the tutorials and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56879616/305865) excellent explanation, but I'm still stuck.

So my question is: How do I rewrite `NotifyController` so it calls a method in my Bot class (the one implementing `ActivityHandler`) - just like `BotController` (from `EchoBot`) does?

Or, if that's better: How do I get a reference to the `UserProfile` in the message handler in `NotifyController`?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Accessing User Data in NotifyController. This didn't work because NotifyController doesn't get a reference to the IBot object in its constructor (can I get one? how?).

Using a timer inside the bot. Instead of triggering proactive events through separate HTTP requests processed in NotifyController, I tried starting a timer in the class deriving from ActivityHandler (i.e. IBot). This didn't work because the bot is transient and bot objects are created and disposed for every action...

Comment: Implementing NotifyController like BotController so I could call OnTurnAsync from there as well. Didn't work: when calling the HTTP endpoint, the browser displays "Upgrade to WebSocket is required.", and OnTurnAsync doesn't get called.

Merging both controllers (adding another Route handler to BotController) had the same effect.

And probably some other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it to work.

Basically I duplicated all the code for the conversationReferences, because those get stored in the Bot and are used in NotifyController.

Some code, in case somebody else is trying to do the same:

### Startup.cs

Create another Singleton.

```
services.AddSingleton<ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserProfile>>();
```

### In the bot class

I have a variable storing `UserProfile`s just like the one for `ConversationReference`s

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserProfile> _userProfiles;
```

The constructor now starts like this

```
public RmindrBot(ConversationState conversationState, 
   UserState userState,
   ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences,
   ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserProfile> userProfiles)
{
    _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
    _userProfiles = userProfiles;
    ...
```

(I think this is the most surprising bit for me - didn't think the framework would just magically figure out the new signature.)

A method for adding references:

```
private void AddConversationReference(Activity activity)
{
    var conversationReference = activity.GetConversationReference();
    _conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(
        conversationReference.User.Id,
        conversationReference, 
           (key, newValue) => conversationReference);
}
```

...which is called in `OnMessageActivityAsync`:

```
var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());
userProfile.ID = turnContext.Activity.From.Id;
AddUserProfile(userProfile);
```

### NotifyController

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserProfile> _userProfiles;

public NotifyController(
    IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences,
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserProfile> userProfiles)
{
    _adapter = adapter;
    _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
    _userProfiles = userProfiles;
    ...
```

And then we can finally use it in the callback method and match the user to their ID:

```
private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var userProfile = _userProfiles[turnContext.Activity.From.Id];

    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("proactive hello " + userProfile.ID);
}
```